# Anglesharp - How to get ratings & reviews from a Yelp site?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, web-scraping, anglesharp

I want to try my hand and webscraping.  I've noticed that Anglesharp is pretty good for the .Net environment.  I'm trying to get a list of all the descriptions and ratings from a yelp site and I don't get any errors or any results.  Here's a subset of what the html looks like (more detailed in "https://www.yelp.ca/biz/walmart-toronto-12"):

```
<div class="rating-very-large">
    <i class="star-img stars_2" title="2.0 star rating">
        <img alt="2.0 star rating" class="offscreen" height="303" src="//s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_styleguide/c2252a4cd43e/assets/img/stars/stars_map.png" width="84">
    </i>
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="2.0">
</div>
<p itemprop="description" lang="en">This Walmart still terrifies me<br><br>Baby things can be found on the back right of the lower level. Godspeed.</p> 

<div class="rating-very-large">
    <i class="star-img stars_1" title="1.0 star rating">
        <img alt="1.0 star rating" class="offscreen" height="303" src="//s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_styleguide/c2252a4cd43e/assets/img/stars/stars_map.png" width="84">
    </i>
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="1.0">
</div>
<p itemprop="description" lang="en">Wow I don&#39;t even know where to begin, </p>
```

Here's my query:

```
var config = var config = new Configuration().WithJavaScript().WithCss();
var parser = new HtmlParser(config);
var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync("https://www.yelp.ca/biz/walmart-toronto-12");

//Do something with LINQ
var descriptionListItemsLinq = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "p" && m.Id.Contains("description"));
foreach (var element in descriptionListItemsLinq)
{
    element.Text().Dump();
}
```

How do I get a list of the user reviews (descriptions) and ratings?

Answer (score 0):

I checked `HTML` source of https://www.yelp.ca/biz/walmart-toronto-12. As I expected the user reviews are in `JSON` format. You should not use `AngleSharp` in this scenario.

The photo below is extracted from the `HTML` source.

[image]

and here is a parsed version of the `JSON`:

[image]

It's a `JSON`and you can deserialize it with `Newtonsoft.Json`. Just extract the `JSON` and read what you need from it.